# how to redirect laravel website using .htaccess or bootstrap file change

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

how to redirect laravel website using .htaccess or bootstrap file change

I have a domain `www.mydm.com/folder/public` but maximum url says my.mydm.com how can i tell my domain  my.mydm.com to hit is equal to `www.mydm.com/folder/public` laravel

Wrote this

```sh
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule /assets www.mydm.com/folder/public [R=301,L]
```

does not help me

Any idea please guide thanks in advance

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### step 1:

Rename File server.php INTO index.php

#### step 2:

Update `.htaccess`

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```